# Where to store random values in Magento database

Tags: magento

Where/how would I store a value in the Magento database, such as the last time a process ran?
I have an extension that updates data in the database, and I want to timestamp the last time that was run. Basically, is there a table with a key -> value pair that I can put anything into?

Comment: Not fully clear.Any issue in custom table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to looking for tracking of scheduler/process than you can look into this plugin(http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html). If you want to store some smaller value than you can save it in config table with or without serialize data.

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('MY_PROCESS_NAME', $value );
```